# Should tags be pluralised?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed just now from the answer by RegDwight to [this question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/should-the-nouns-verbs-adjectives-tags-only-be-used-for-general-discussions) that the tags are pluralised.

However we have [meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) and not [meanings](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings), [word-choice](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) instead of [word-choices](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choices) and so on.  (Even the 'official' [discussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) instead of [discussions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussions) for meta.)

Shall we decided to use, in general, the plural or singular form for tags?  (Incidentally, we have [tags](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) instead of [tag](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) but this should definitely not be seen as an exception, since the discussion is about all tags and not just one of them ;).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some tags, it doesn't make sense to use plural since it describes a single concept. You could test this by a heuristic I just came up with: saying "this question is about ______".

- This question is about [pronunciation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation).
- This question is about [synonyms](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms).
- This question is about [word-choice](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice).
- This question is about [nouns](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns).

For other tags I suggest that we use the plural forms. It feels more natural, and was also the [decision on EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags).

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible for us to add this little heuristic in pop-up text near the desolate empty tag box when one asks a question.  I think it would help people.

Comment: +1. Basically what ELU has found out works like a charm is this: prefer plural where 1. both singular and plural *make sense*, and 2. both singular and plural *are actually used* by the people tagging their own questions. So, while [grammaticalities], [punctuations], [politenesses] are obviously ruled out by (1), [meanings] and [discussions] are *theoretically* more of a gray area, but it turns out that *in practice* nobody actually uses them, so they are ruled out by (2) as it makes no sense to *force* them onto people.

Comment: @Glen: I don't think that would be necessary as long as we keep making tag synonyms when the "wrong" numerus is used.

Answer (score 3):

#### Always use singular form.

I don't know how the search-engine works, but I guess it is more easy to find 'tags' if you search for 'tag' as the other way round, because there is no simple rule to build the plural form. (child => children, man => men, ...).

And if I think about a search, I would search for tag, noun, synonym. Only with the sentence in mind 'This ... is about ...', I would build the plural form.

For a simple rule, always to use singular makes more sense than always using plural form.